# change toggle button background color in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

Toggle Button Background color should get changed on its click/IsChecked event.
Please look into the below code:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="BtnArea" Content="{Binding Area, Source={StaticResource Labels}}" Style="{StaticResource FirstButton}" Click="Toggle_Click"  Background="Chocolate" />


 private void Toggle_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ToggleButton obj = (ToggleButton)sender;
            ((ToggleButton)sender).Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(155, 0, 255, 0));
            obj.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(155, 0, 55, 0));
        }
```

Comment: This code is not working properly

Comment: Is there any solution for this?